# Is there a way to set the workspace on selected features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, workspace, context-menu

i´ve built in a tool for arccatalog which transfers GIS Files into shape Files.
Everything is working so far, but i want it a bit more customer friendly.

Atm it looks like this:

You can right click on the file (here MapInfo .tab file) in the catalog tree and choose in the context menu "Konvertierung in WGS 1984"

[image]

then the tool interface opens and you can choose your input and output file:

[image]

But its annoying to choose all the time the input in the file system again.
I want that my selected file from the catalog tree is already listed as input data.

So my question is:

Is there any way to set the workspace from the input data in my tool TO the selected file on which i right clicked (here: Blk1403.Tab), i.e. the Filepath which is listed on the top in arccatalog.

[image]

The Tool is just a simple Model built with ModelBuilder, it contains some Py scripts and some tools from the Toolbox.
Then the Model is implemented as a Button with the Add-in Wizard.
Then it is draged & dropped into the context menu of the "Text-contextmenu" via Customize Mode.

The first py script of the Model calls the ogr2ogr.exe and looks so far right now:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

import sys
import string
import os
import arcgisscripting
import arcpy

gp = arcgisscripting.create()

inPath1 = sys.argv[1]

outformat = sys.argv[2]
outPath1 = sys.argv[3]


ogrstring = ' -f "' + outformat + '" "' + outPath1 + '" "' + inPath1 + '""' 
callstring = '"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /C" "R:\\RBS\\Software\\FWTools2.4.7\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe" ' + ogrstring

gp.addmessage(callstring)

os.system(callstring)
```

Comment: How were the context menu items implemented? Also I don't believe this is possible without using ArcObjects.

Comment: The context menu is implemented via 
Customize -> Customize Mode -> Edit "Text Contextmenu" in the Toolbar "Context menu"

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to change the directory based off the file selected in the dialog, correct?

Try something like this:

```
shapefile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #whatever index it is
directory = os.path.dirname(shapefile) #pull the directory from the shapefile
arcpy.env.workspace = directory #set the arcpy workspace to the directory
```

That should work for you if you are assigning the shapefile in the dialog box.  If that isn't correct, give me a better explanation of your work flow, and I might be able to help more.

Comment: He wants to have the file he right clicks on to automatically populate into the tool he selects.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, then you might be able to do the same thing I was doing without the GetParameterAsText.  If there is somewhere in the script where you have access to the file itself (in this case .Tab) you should be able to do a directory call on it and then change the workspace before any work is done.

Comment: Cheers Ian, this is exactly what I plan to do!
I want that my selected file on which I right click with the mouse is listed automatically as my input file in my tool!